# Function empty_cpu() returns a result of TensorBase class to a variable of Tensor class in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I'm reading source code of PyTorch and find some weird code:

1. In `aten/src/ATen/native/TensorFactories.cpp`, a function named `empty_cpu()` with a Tensor as return type:

```
Tensor empty_cpu(IntArrayRef size, c10::optional<ScalarType> dtype_opt,
c10::optional<Layout> layout_opt, c10::optional<Device> device_opt,
c10::optional<bool> pin_memory_opt, c10::optional<c10::MemoryFormat>
memory_format_opt)
 {
return at::detail::empty_cpu(size, dtype_opt, layout_opt, device_opt,
pin_memory_opt, memory_format_opt);
 }
```

2. The function calls another `empty_cpu(at::detail::empty_cpu())` which defines in `aten/src/ATen/EmptyTensor.cpp` and whose return type is TensorBase

```
TensorBase empty_cpu(
    IntArrayRef size,
    c10::optional<ScalarType> dtype_opt,
    c10::optional<Layout> layout_opt,
    c10::optional<Device> device_opt,
    c10::optional<bool> pin_memory_opt,
    c10::optional<c10::MemoryFormat> memory_format_opt) {
  TORCH_INTERNAL_ASSERT_DEBUG_ONLY(device_or_default(device_opt).type() == DeviceType::CPU);
  TORCH_INTERNAL_ASSERT_DEBUG_ONLY(layout_or_default(layout_opt) == Layout::Strided);
  auto pin_memory = pinned_memory_or_default(pin_memory_opt);
  auto dtype = dtype_or_default(dtype_opt);
  return empty_cpu(size, dtype, pin_memory, memory_format_opt);
}
```

3. TensorBase is base class of Tensor

My question: Why the second function `at::native::empty_cpu()` could return a base class "TensorBase" to first function `empty_cpu()` which need sub class "Tensor"？
Any suggestion will be appreciated, thank you~!

Comment: Seeing as Tensor is an extension of TensorBase, it is okay to cast a Tensor to its TensorBase format. Likely, this is done to keep things more modular elsewhere